# From pixel coordinate to opengl coordinate

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, augmented-reality

As i see in opengl the coordinates are between -1 and 1, I want to render a object using opengl,I have the first position where to render the object in pixel coordinate, but I don't know how to convert the pixel coordinates to opengl coordinates. I am working on an android application using java.

public class FirstOpenGLProjectRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

```
private static final String A_POSITION = "a_Position";
private static final String A_COLOR = "a_Color";
private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 4;
private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
private static final int STRIDE =
        (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT) * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

private final FloatBuffer vertexData;
private final Context context;

private int program;
private int aPositionLocation;
private int aColorLocation;

private static final String U_MATRIX = "u_Matrix";
private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
private int uMatrixLocation;
private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];



public FirstOpenGLProjectRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;


 //
    // Vertex data is stored in the following manner:
    //
    // The first two numbers are part of the position: X, Y
    // The next three numbers are part of the color: R, G, B
    //
    float[] tableVerticesWithTriangles = {
            // Order of coordinates: X, Y, R, G, B


            // Triangle Fan
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1.5f, 1f, 1f, 1f,
            -0.5f, -0.8f, 0f, 1f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            0.5f, -0.8f, 0f, 1f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            0.5f, 0.8f, 0f, 2f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            -0.5f, 0.8f, 0f, 2f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            -0.5f, -0.8f, 0f, 1f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
        // Line 1
            -0.5f, 0f, 0f, 1.5f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
            0.5f, 0f, 0f, 1.5f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
        // Mallets
            0f, -0.4f, 0f, 1.25f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
            0f, 0.4f, 0f, 1.75f, 1f, 0f, 0f

    };

    vertexData = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(tableVerticesWithTriangles.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

    vertexData.put(tableVerticesWithTriangles);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    String vertexShaderSource = TextResourceReader
            .readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.imple_vertex_shader);
    String fragmentShaderSource = TextResourceReader
            .readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader);

    int vertexShader = ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
    int fragmentShader = ShaderHelper
            .compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);

    program = ShaderHelper.linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    if (LoggerConfig.ON) {
        ShaderHelper.validateProgram(program);
    }

    glUseProgram(program);

    uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MATRIX);

    aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);
    aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_COLOR);

    // Bind our data, specified by the variable vertexData, to the vertex
    // attribute at location A_POSITION_LOCATION.
    vertexData.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
            false, STRIDE, vertexData);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

    // Bind our data, specified by the variable vertexData, to the vertex
    // attribute at location A_COLOR_LOCATION.
    vertexData.position(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT);
    glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
            false, STRIDE, vertexData);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

}


@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    // Set the OpenGL viewport to fill the entire surface.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 45, (float) width
            / (float) height, 1f, 10f);



    setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);

    translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, -2.5f);
    rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, -60f, 1f, 0f, 0f);

    final float[] temp = new float[16];
    multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);
```

/
    }

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // Clear the rendering surface.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Assign the matrix
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the table.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

    // Draw the center dividing line.
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 6, 2);

    // Draw the first mallet.
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 8, 1);

    // Draw the second mallet.
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 9, 1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, if you simply want to draw 2D primitives to the screen, you want to *not* apply any 3D model, view, or projection matrices (i.e., use a shader that just passes the position through unaltered, or set those matrices to identity). Then you basically get to specify the coordinates of stuff to draw in clip-space directly. clip-space is actually a [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) and clip-space coordinates are actually four-dimensional [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), but you don't really have to worry about that for now. As long as you set the fourth coordinate *w* to 1, clip-space coordinates will directly correspond to normalized device coordinates, which is this -1 to 1 coordinate system you already seem to be familiar with.

So with that out of the way, how do we get from pixel coordinates to normalized device coordinates? Well, what we need to do is map the [0..*w*) and [0..*h*) range of *x* and *y* pixel indices to positions in the [-1, 1] range (where *w* and *h* are the number of pixels of the viewport/screen in *x* and *y* direction respectively). The one important thing to note here is that pixel locations in OpenGL correspond to the *centers* of the cells of the sampling grid. That means pixel (0, 0) does not fall onto the lower left corner, but is offset by "1/2 of a pixel". If you excuse my ASCII art:

```
    |     |     |     |   
    +-----+-----+-----+---
    |  o  |  o  |  o  |   
    +-----+-----+-----+---
    |  o  |  o  |  o  |   
    +-----+-----+-----+---
    |  X  |  o  |  o  |   
    +-----+-----+-----+---
(-1, -1)
```

The distance between pixel locations is 1/w in *x* and 1/h in *y* direction. Thus, the location of pixel (*x*, *y*) in normalized device coordinates is:

```
x_ndc = 2.0f * (x + 0.5f) / w - 1.0f;
y_ndc = 2.0f * (y + 0.5f) / h - 1.0f;
```

And the homogeneous coordinates for a vertex to be placed at that point would be `(x_ndc, y_ndc, -1.0f, 1.0f)`. Note that the z-coordinate can be whatever depth you want to place your 2D element at (-1 corresponds to the near plane, +1 to the far plane).

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael Kenzel